# Group of matrices (a b; 0 1), a>0. Name?

Tags: representation-theory

What's the standard name for the group of matrices
$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\;
\middle|
\;
a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a>0
\right\}\ \subseteq \mathrm{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})?
$$

Comment: I vote for $\operatorname{Aff}^+(r)$, where $r=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, y=1\}$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Why is it not just $\mathrm{Aff}^+(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Someone I know called it "the ax+b group".

Comment: @Milten It is isomorphic, but I wanted to stress that the natural action of that subgroup on $\Bbb R^2$ transforms affinely that special affine subspace to itself. (I wrote $(x,y)$, but of course it should have been $\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$)